# Differential equation $x\cdot f'(x)\cdot\left(f(x)+1\right)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, lambert-w

In a proof of the series expansion of the Lambert-W-function, I need that it is the only non-zero function satisfying:
$$
x\cdot f'(x)\cdot\left(f(x)+1\right)=f(x)
$$
Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x (f(x)+1)} \iff \frac{f'(x) (f(x)+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x}\stackrel{\int}{\iff}\log f(x)+f(x)=\log x+c_1$$

Solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: @user109899 Glad I could help :) You can accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x f(x)+1} \iff \frac{f'(x) (f(x)+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x}?$$ How did you obtain that?

Comment: I think UserX has just missed the brackets, but it is equivalent to the original statement.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I missed the brackets, used them for the rest of the solution though so the result didn't change.